# Designing a REST API endpoint that accepts a lot of data as input

Tags: api, rest

Let's assume we're designing REST API. We have some entity, let's call it `foo`

So the endpoint that returns a list of `foo` entities filtered according some predicates would look like:

```
GET /foos?filtering-parameters-here
```

The issue though is that the size of the `filtering-parameters` payload is potentially HUGE. In some cases it may easily be more than 6-7kb.

Some clients (browsers) are trimming the URL in case if it is of that size.

The "obvious" solution is to change it to `POST` and send parameters in the body. But it will make the endpoint not semantically clean.

So what would be the correct RESTful way?

Comment: Primarily opinion based? Seriously? And even -1. SO, I don't understand you

Comment: Split up your API, as if you require 6KB of parameters for a **GET**, the API is likely doing way too much...

Comment: @ircmaxell: not in this case - they are predicate filters for the entities list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've heard the recommendation of using `POST` in such circumstances, but not to merely accept parameters.

Instead, a `POST` request is fired with the complex filtering data as the message body, and this predictably *creates a resource*; let's call it a `search`:

```
POST /search HTTP/1.1
```

The response identifies via `Location` the result set:

```
Location: http://example.com/search/798342
```

A subsequent `GET` request can be made against the location, returning the result set. This works *particularly* well when the result set may take some time to generate (*which could be the case given complex filtering rules*) and maintains alignment with the expectations of HTTP.

```
GET /search/798342 HTTP/1.1
```

If the search results are not ready, yield a `404`.

Searches, like anything else, can/should be represented as resources. An added benefit is caching. If you cache the results of a complex operation, the cache lifetime can be communicated from the search result set resource.

Comment: I've used this pattern more times than I could've imagined now. Moreover there are great ways to extend it, for example: `POST`-ing against an existing search to create a sub-filter.